# jQuery selector input[type=text]:nth-child(2) not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, bootstrap-5

I'm unable to use the ids or the class names associated with the inputs due to how they're randomly generated on input.

The render looks like this:

```
<div class='dateSearch'>
  <label>Label 1</label>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_1'/>
  <span>Icon</span>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_2'/>
  <span>Icon</span>
  <input type='button' id='searchBtn'/>
</div>
```

I have no control of the render and can not change any content. So instead I was trying to grab the second text input and add a label before it.

```
<script>
  $('<label>Label 2</label>').insertBefore('.dateSearch input[type=text]:nth-child(2)')
</script>
```

`.dateSearch input[type=text]` will add the label infront of both text inputs, but `:nth-child(2)` doesn't seem to want to work.

I've tried  `.dateSearch > input:nth-child(2)` and that failed to work as well. I just wanted to add a label before the second input element.

```js
  $('<label>Label 2</label>').insertBefore('.dateSearch input[type=text]:nth-child(2)')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='dateSearch'>
  <label>Label 1</label>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_1'/>
  <span>Icon</span>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_2'/>
  <span>Icon</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
</div>
```

Want it to look like this:

**Label_1** [ *Input Text* ] (*Icon*) **Label_2** [ *Input Text* ] (*Icon*) [ *Button* ]

Comment: Would your selector make sense if you made it `input:nth-child(2)[type=text]` or `$(".dateSearch").find(":nth-child(2)").filter("input[type=text]")`?   `:nth-child` is always nth-child regardless of whatever other filters you apply

Comment: Your `random_id_2` is `:nth-child(4)` not (2)

Comment: True, which makes using `:nth-child()` inherently clumsy and possibly fragile. Better to target by element type and index, if not something more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)? That gets you around the child selector problem because you can target elements by type as well.

Don't forget to put a `for` attribute on the label for accessibility if you can.

```js
const secondInput = $('.dateSearch input[type=text]').eq(1); // zero-based
const secondInputId = secondInput.attr('id'); // optional, but wise
const label = $('<label>Label 2</label>');
label.attr('for', secondInputId); // optional, but wise

label.insertBefore(secondInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dateSearch'>
  <label>Label 1</label>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_1' />
  <span>Icon</span>
  <input type='text' id='random_id_2' />
  <span>Icon</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
</div>
```